# Subset based on a variable value interpreted as a column

Tags: r

I'm trying to subset a data frame based on a variable I'm passing into it. My goal is to form a column name inside a function using some values I am passing into it and filter on that newly form column name.

Here's a reproducible example:

```
var_as_col_name <- function(df, col_var, filter_var) {
  subset(df, col_var == filter_var)
}

# this should return what subset(df, cty == 18) would return
var_as_col_name(mpg,"cty", 18)

# this should return what subset(df, cyl == 4) would return
var_as_col_name(mpg,"cyl", 4)
```

Also, apart from the filters on `mpg$cty` and `mpg$cyl` above, I might have another filter that is hardcoded, which I don't want to change, i.e. my requirement should hold for more than one filter. Is there a better approach without using subset (since it is meant for interactive use)?

I am doing this because I have some columns in my dataset like `t_1`, `t_2`, `t_3`...`t_24` and I need to filter on either of them and another `flag` column, so I'm doing:

`df_1 <- subset(my_df,flag == 0 & t_1 > 0 & t_1 < 1)` when I want  data after filtering on t_1

`df_2 <- subset(my_df,flag == 1 & t_2 > 0 & t_2 < 1)` when I want data after filtering on t_2
...

Instead of this I was thinking of writing a function that takes:

1. `n` from 1 to 24, filters on that `t_n`
2. takes 1 or 0 for the `flag`.

and then returns the subsetted dataframe that I want.

Let me know if you need clarification on the question and thanks for your help...

Comment: `subset` should not be used for programming. Do `var_as_col_name <- function(df, col_var, filter_var) {df[ df[col_var]==filter_var,]}` instead using the square brackets.